# Set a Google Form's elements when a user is entering for submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api, google-forms

Suppose I have the following:

**Spreadsheet A**

[image: Spreedsheet A]

and I want to show the users a different question every time they enter a form for submitting (they see only one question in the form):

**Form A**

[image: Form A]

**But there's another more difficult catch:**

The form must check with the spreadsheet data which bands are still "unrated" by this user, and only show a question for one of those bands. If the user has rated every band in the spreadsheet, then the form should only show a "There are no more bands to rate" message.

And, the submit of the responses should be in this way:

**Form A Responses**

[image: Form A Responses]

Is this possible with Google Forms, App Script, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not possible with apps script. you cannot modify the form at show time.

at most you can adjust the form (during onFormSubmit) for the next user to see. thus its impossible to customize for a specific user and you can also run into timing issues even if user is not important.